# match data from PHP Array and display what does not match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have this PHP Code that selects from a database and creates an array with the data

```
$sql="SELECT * from voip_emergency_services_data ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $ListData1[] = $result["number"];
    }
}
```

this one does the same on a different table, also connecting to a different database on a different server

```
$sql="SELECT * from channel_did ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$pbx01_conn) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $ListData2[] = $result["did"];
    }
}
```

how can i match the data in both of the Arrays and then display what does not match

for example, each row in the `channel_did` table should match with a row in the `voip_emergency_services_data` table based on the `did` column and the `number` column

Comment: Different database on a different server?  Can you not use the [`FEDERATED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/federated-storage-engine.html) storage engine to link them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question, this gives what is in 1 but not in 2 and what is in 2 but not in 1:

```
$notIn1 = array_diff($ListData2, $ListData1);
$notIn2 = array_diff($ListData1, $ListData2);

echo implode(',', $notIn1) . ' are in list 2 but not 1';
echo implode(',', $notIn2) . ' are in list 1 but not 2';

foreach($notIn1 as $value) {
    echo "$value is not in list 1";
}
```

Comment: i am getting these errors: Warning: array_diff() [function.array-diff]: Argument #1 is not an array in /home/integra/public_html/admin/customer/voip_emergency_data_errors.php on line 37


Warning: array_diff() [function.array-diff]: Argument #1 is not an array in /home/integra/public_html/admin/customer/voip_emergency_data_errors.php on line 42

Comment: i now just get the word 'Array' nothing else :(

Comment: so i need to do anything with the arrays after outside the loop?

Comment: Well sure, you didn't ask anything about that.  Do you need to know how to display array values?  That's a different question.  Either `implode()` or foreach and echo.

Comment: you mean you get the word 'Array' when trying to display the contents of $notIn1 and $notIn2? how are you trying to do so?

Comment: how can i use foreach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of functions you can use that would solve this.

[array_diff($array1,$array2)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) will find all items that are in $array1 but not $array2.

[array_intersect($array1,$array2)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) will find all items that are in $array1 and $array2.  $array1 will be the master that is being compared against, so array2 can contain items that are not in $array1.